# Firebase advanced fuzzy search with levenshtein ordering and word by word

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

Search is one of the most important parts of my current application. It needs to feel like a fast, accurate, global search. The app is based on Firebase and I find Firebase's equalTo() / startAt() combination to be fairly lacking in this aspect.

[image: Current situation]

**What I want to achieve:**

- The results ordered by relevance
- To match word by word (so *öö pime* should yield above result)
- Search in multiple properties (so *põhjala pime* should yield above result)
- Fuzzy search (levenshtein?) - *pojala* should match *Põhjala*

**What I already did**

Instead of using equalTo(), I download an entire branch (for example beers), and loop through it, performing my own `contains()`. This works and is reasonably fast. However, it lacks all the things I mentioned. Here's the current code.

```
           final ArrayList<SearchBeerAdapter.BeerBrewery> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
            FirebaseUtil.getBeersRef().orderByChild("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot ogDS) {
                    int childCounter = 0;
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: ogDS.getChildren()){
                        childCounter++;
                        if (resultCounter[0] < 5) {
                            final Beer beer = ds.getValue(Beer.class);
                            final String beerId = ds.getKey();

                            // Limit to five results and remove listener
                            final int finalChildCounter = childCounter;
                            FirebaseUtil.getBreweriesRef().child(beer.getBreweryId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Brewery brewery = dataSnapshot.getValue(Brewery.class);
                                    if (beer.getFullName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) || brewery.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                                        resultCounter[0] = resultCounter[0] + 1;
                                        if (resultCounter[0] < 5) {
                                            searchResults.add(new SearchBeerAdapter.BeerBrewery(beer, brewery, beerId));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Initialize the adapter once we've hit the end of our results
                                    if (finalChildCounter == ogDS.getChildrenCount()){
                                        SearchBeerAdapter sa = new SearchBeerAdapter(searchResults,glide);
                                        rv.setAdapter(sa);
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

I'm guessing what needs to be done is each match needs to get a score in `searchResults` and after we're done looping the ArrayList needs to be sorted by this score. My main question would boil down to how to get the best score considering above criteria. Any libraries or code samples would be extremely welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be querying a firebase database directly for searching, it's not built for that. There are other tools available to help with this and you can look into algolia.com which I was pointed to before as a potential solution.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't the best solution for me at this point. I see the appeal of a dedicated search provider in the long run, but for short term it means syncing my data to a second party, possibly having to pay a second party or have a user facing logo which means nothing to them. I'll save this link, but for now my app is a bit too small for this.

Comment: And to add to that, I'm not actually searching in Firebase. I'm just querying and then searching in the resulting array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some failed attempts at doing my own scoring and Googling a lot I found [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy). This rather nice library uses levenshtein, but has a `extractTop()` and `extractAll()` functionality. It is actually a partial fuzzy search and perfect for this case.

The library just searches in Strings, but you can work around that by creating a string only array and a reference array.